# What does PhoneGap use for a database?

Tags: cordova

I am using Phonegap to create an app and I am using webstorage. This is apparently depreceated by W3C and there are many names for HTML storage, websql webstorage local storage.

Can anyone explain which Phonegap relies upon, if it will suddenly be dropped due to W3Cs depreciation and are there other option?

Comment: PhoneGap relies on no database at all, why should it?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap relies on no database at all.

But you can use SQLite DB with Phonegap to develop application as other option for Database.